# SDKROOT path for latest SDK

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4.5, ld

I am using Xcode to build an old code and specify `SDKROOT=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX"${HOST_VERSION}".sdk/`

I want to specify SDKROOT for latest SDK that comes pre-installed (?) on the system. e.g. I am on `10.8` already and I want to specify `SDKROOT` with -syslibroot, but there is no such SDK in `/Developer/SDKs/`. Should i just ignore syslibroot altogether if `SDK_VERSION == HOST_VERSION`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Newer Xcode versions have the SDKs inside the Xcode.app bundle, e.g.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
```

You get the list of installed SDKs together with their path by running

```
xcodebuild -sdk -version
```

from the command line.

If you have installed the "Command Line Tools" (Xcode Preferences -> Downloads -> Components) then compiling without "-syslibroot" should be equivalent to compiling against the latest SDK.

See the help to the  "Command Line Tools" package:

> Downloading this package will install copies of the core command line
>   tools and system headers into system folders, including the LLVM
>   compiler, linker, and build tools.

Answer (score 14):

As stated in another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741675/how-to-get-the-path-of-latest-sdk-available-on-mac):

```
xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path
```

Answer (score 6):

With `xcodebuild -version -sdk macosx10.7 Path` you can get the Path to the OS X 10.7 SDK.
You may replace 10.7 by `${SDK_VERSION}` or `${HOST_VERSION}` depending on your needs.
I know of no command to obtain the version of OS X, which could be used to obtain the Path to the SDK matching the version of OS X currently running.

Note: for `xcodebuild` to work, the user must have configured `xcode-select` properly, for example `xcode-select -switch /Application/Xcode.app`.

Answer (score 0):

CommandLineTools was outdated, reinstalling Command Line Tools fixed the issue:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I don't particularly understand why this was downvoted. More often than not `xcode-select --install` proves to be the correct answer.