# How to get the path of latest SDK available on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos

I know that in order to get xcode install directory from command line I have to use `xcode-select -print-path`. The result is something like: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Is there any command to get latest SDK folder? I need as result something like: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/`

If it's not possible to get the SDK complete path I need at least SDK number and I'll try to build the path.

Comment: `xcodebuild -sdk -version` shows information about all installed SDKs.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for help. The result is very verbose, but I think I can manage to parse it to get the folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure this could be cleaned up a bit, and probably done in a single line of perl, but here's an easy approach:

```
sdkparam=`xcodebuild -showsdks | awk '/^$/{p=0};p; /OS X SDKs:/{p=1}' | tail -1 | cut -f3`
sdkpath=`xcodebuild -version $sdkparam Path`
```

The point of the awk is to print the "OS X SDKs" block from `-showsdks`. Then take the last line of it and the 3rd field (it's separated with tabs). Then we ask `xcodebuild` for the path to that sdk.

Answer (score 59):

The easiest way I found so far is:

```
xcrun --show-sdk-path
```

Answer (score 26):

To be more precise,

```
xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path
```